# Why Can't I add a db file to MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql

I am trying to add a database file to a schema I have created in MySQL Workbench so I can generate an ERD Diagram from it. It does not allow me to do it when I try to add it. It gives me the following error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'TRANSACTION' at line 1
>
> Operation failed with exitcode 1

The file that I am trying to import is called `mmssms.db`

Comment: The error is actually telling you evrything you need to know. For us without seeing your query (line 1) it is not possible to help you...

Comment: Where is my line 1? Is it in the database file itself. I haven't opened the file as of yet, I have only tried to import it.

Comment: You should know where your line 1 is. Look at your query...

Comment: I have not written any query. Im just trying to import a random db file into workbench

Comment: DDL statements do not run in transactions in MySQL, so you have some garabage left in your sql file that you need to remove.

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to use the facility to import an SQL file to import a database file.

You can't do that — a database file is not an SQL file.

It is the responsibility of your database server, not the client, to read your database.

Configure MySQL Workbench to talk to your MariaDB or MySQL server which should be hosting your database.

Comment: TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `words_segments` (
 `blockid` INTEGER,
 `block` BLOB,
 PRIMARY KEY(`blockid`)

Comment: that is the first line of the database file

Comment: Nope, you misunderstood the question. In MySQL Workbench you can reverse engineer an sql script consisting of schema definition sql statements into an EER diagram. This way you can do your data modelling without having an actual database available.